# How to access jasperreports report elements from java

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a really simple report, based on one of the samples, it produces something like this:

```
<integer> <name of group> <number of items in the group>
```

I want to add a hypertext link to  that will open up a file containing the elements of contained in the  group.

This is how I load up my report for generation:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("./report.jasper");

Map params = new HashMap();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("<connection string>);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, con);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "./report.html");
```